# Unable to open a new tab in the browser. It loads the 2nd url in the same tab

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to open a new tab in the browser. 
But however it open the second URL in the same tab.

Code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By; 
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ChromeFlock {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       WebDriver driver;       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Automation\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");      driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        String baseUrl = "http://www.google.co.uk/";
        driver.get(baseUrl);

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"t");
        driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);

        driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use JavascriptExecutor as following:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('http://www.facebook.com');");
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are not switching to the new tab, which is resulting in launching the 2nd link on the parent tab only.

You can use Robot class to open a new tab by simulating pressing of keyboard's Ctrl+t keys. Then you need to **switch to the new tab using driver.switchTo()** command.

For code snippet and details check this [Open a new tab in Selenium](http://artoftesting.com/automationTesting/open-a-new-tab-in-selenium-webdriver-java.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use keyboard emulation:

```
new Actions(driver).sendKeys(Keys.Control + 'w').build.perform(); // or + 't'
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
```

or using JavaScriptExecutor:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).ExecuteScript("window.open('http://www.facebook.com','_blank');");
```

Comment: Still the same issue. Opens the second link the same tab and not the new one

Comment: @ShaikhFarzan but have your previous tab finalize the loading? Try to increase timeouts

Comment: @ShaikhFarzan, at least try to add `.Build().Perform()` to the end of your function `driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab)` to initialize a chain execution.